# How to write custom middleware and pass to socket-io custom event pipeline?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using socket-io for building a chat app. And I have  many custom events and for each event I want to pass different middleware function? In my case `io.use(somefunction())` not working! I want to pass middleware function to my custom event like this? `io.on('my-custom-event', middleware, function() { ... })`

**Socket-io route Code :** (*Path : /routes/user.js*)

```
module.exports.user_status_info = function (io,socket) {
    socket.on('custom-event', io.use(require('../../middleware/_chat-validation-middlewares/custom-event').validate(io,socket)), function (data, callback) { ... }
}
```

**Middleware :** (*Path : /middleware/custom-event.js*)

```
module.exports.validate = function (io,socket) {
    io.use((socket, next) => {
        console.log("I AM A MIDDLEWARE...")
        next();
    }); }
```

> **Current Implementation throwing error when I am trying to pass middleware in route pipeline.**

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like
note that you do not have to use your data on the socket object and can only use it on your specific event

server:

```
  io.use(async (socket, next) => {
try {
  const token = socket.handshake.query.token;
  const payload = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
  socket.userId = payload.id;
  socket.name = payload.username;
  console.log({ socketisd: socket.userId, name: socket.name });
  next();
} catch (err) { }
});
```

and then just use the Socket object, later on, to get all data needed

client:

```
      const [socket, setSocket] = React.useState(null);

  const setupSocket = () => {

    const token = sessionStorage.getItem("yourjwtToken");
    if (token && !socket) {
      const newSocket = io("/", {
        query: {
          token,
        },
        path: '/socket'//if you have one
      });

      newSocket.on("disconnect", () => {
        console.log("Socket disconnect");
      });

      newSocket.on("connect", () => {
        console.log("Socket Connected");
      });

      setSocket(newSocket);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUser && !socket) setupSocket();
    //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [socket]);
```